# Imagem de fundo em um titulo HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html5, background-image

olá estou com dificuldades para colocar um fundo em um titulo na minha pagina

trecho em html

```html
 <div id="about-area">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">                    
           <h3 class="main-title fundo">Assinatura Anual  </h3>
         </div>
```

[essa é a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9CZA.png)

assim esta definido meu css

```
.main-title {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 65px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.main-title.fundo {
  background-image: url('/img/graficofundo.svg');
  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  
}
```

[Resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNoE6.png) ,
[como ficou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIBA8.png)

estou tentando fazer com que a imagem ultrapasse o limite e apareça inteira o tamanho esta bacana mas esta cortando um pedaço em cima e embaixo, tem como fazer essa imagem transpassar seu limite?

Comment: A imagem está no fundo do título. Defina as dimensões do título.

Answer (score -2):

Você deveria adicionar a imagem de fundo à uma div externa do texto e não ao texto em si, algo assim:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="fundo">
         <h3 class="main-title">Assinatura Anual</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.fundo {
  background-image: url('/img/graficofundo.svg');
  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
}
```

adicionei um padding também para dar esse efeito de "ultrapassar" o texto que você comentou

Comment: obrigado  Gabriel Vitor, parece fazer  mais sentido assim!

Answer (score -2):

Após várias tentativas e pesquisas, consegui resolver meu problema. Vou compartilhar a solução caso alguém que esteja iniciando como eu tenha a mesma dúvida.

```
  display:block;
  height: 110px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 70px 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px; 
}

.main-title.fundo {
  background-image: url('/img/graficofundo.svg');
  background-size: 450px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;  
}
```

Consegui solucionar o problema adicionando a propriedade display: block;, que faz com que o elemento ocupe toda a largura disponível do seu contêiner pai. Também defini a altura do elemento para height: 110px;. Adicionei um padding-top: 20px; para criar um preenchimento na parte superior, fazendo com que o texto descesse um pouco sobre a imagem. Na parte do fundo, apenas defini o background-size em 450px.

Não tenho certeza se essa foi a solução mais inteligente ou se foi feita de uma maneira correta, mas o resultado final ficou do jeito que eu queria. Se alguém perceber que algo está errado ou é totalmente desnecessário, por favor, dê uma dica para nós que estamos começando.

O Resulado final ficou [assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQcdi.png).